# Creating and plotting a time-series from a multi-dimensional input

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data like :

```
Timestamp, Dimension, Value
t1, d1, v1
t2, d1, v2
t3, d1, v3
...
tn, d2, v4
tn+1, d2, v4
...
tm, d1, v5
...
```

Is there a way with Pandas to convert these to a set of time series that I can plot `d1`, `d2` ...`dn` with timestamp on the x-axis and value on the y-axis

UPDATE:

Output of `df.head().to_dict()`

```
{'Timestamp': {0: 1696603859.706954, 1: 1696603859.707053, 2: 1696603859.707162, 3: 1696603859.707236, 4: 1696603859.707281}, ' Dim': {0: 'WT', 1: 'WH-0x00', 2: 'WH-0x80', 3: 'WH-Others', 4: 'WT-0x00'}, ' Value': {0: 24, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 41}, ' Count': {0: 24, 1: 44, 2: 44, 3: 44, 4: 44}}
```

Comment: `df["Dimension"].plot()`?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt') df["Dimension"].plot` KeyError 'Dimension'

Comment: Please provide your data as code `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: @not_speshal updated in post

Comment: Space in `Dim` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to plot? If it's ` Value` (with the space before the column name as you have), then just `df[" Value"].plot()`. If not, please make your question clearer. For example, do you want a separate line or stacked bar for each " Dim" value?

Comment: Thanks @not_speshal one issue was the Space. I am trying to plot Value per Dim. I.e if There are N Dimensions I want to plot them on a separate graph vs Timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot` to separate each  `Dim` to a new column and then `plot`:

```
output = df.pivot(index="Timestamp", columns=" Dim", values=" Value")
```

```
>>> output.plot(subplots=True)
```

If you want a grid (assuming you have 30 different  `Dim` values:

```
>>> output.plot(subplots=True, layout=(5,6))
```